# httpd.conf: ignore certain directories?

Tags: apache2, alias, httpd.conf

I have an `httpd.conf` file that looks like this:

```
Alias /media/ /var/projects/potato_gun/media/
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/projects/potato_gun/django.wsgi
```

The problem is, I broke all my URLs that start with `/~username` because they get sent off to `django.wsgi` instead. Is there anyway I can get it to ignore any URL that starts with `/~`?

Answer (score 1):

how about AliasMatch?

I think it would be /(*~)media/

Comment: Okay... I could use `AliasMatch` to match stuff, but then how do I simply ignore that matched stuff and let it go through as it would have had I not added those 2 aliases in my question?